# Ubuntu + Oracle cloud 1.16.5 minecraft forge server error. Java illegal access or something

Tags: server, java, minecraft, oracle

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class cpw.mods.modlauncher.SecureJarHandler (in unnamed module @0x5ac154b6) cannot access class sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.util to unnamed module @0x5ac154b6
        at cpw.mods.modlauncher.SecureJarHandler.lambda$static$1(SecureJarHandler.java:45)
        at cpw.mods.modlauncher.api.LamdbaExceptionUtils.uncheck(LamdbaExceptionUtils.java:95)
        at cpw.mods.modlauncher.SecureJarHandler.<clinit>(SecureJarHandler.java:45)
        at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.lambda$new$6(Launcher.java:55)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
        at cpw.mods.modlauncher.api.TypesafeMap.computeIfAbsent(TypesafeMap.java:52)
        at cpw.mods.modlauncher.api.TypesafeMap.computeIfAbsent(TypesafeMap.java:47)
        at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Environment.computePropertyIfAbsent(Environment.java:62)
        at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:55)
        at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:66)
        at net.minecraftforge.server.ServerMain$Runner.runLauncher(ServerMain.java:49)
        at net.minecraftforge.server.ServerMain$Runner.access$100(ServerMain.java:46)
        at net.minecraftforge.server.ServerMain.main(ServerMain.java:43)
```

Comment: Exception in question "main" usless.blob.noQuestionError ...

Comment: There is no question in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try using openJDK 11.

I was running into the same issue, it seems like this version of Forge does have the greatest coding practices.